# How to loop through a cell array of functions, plotting each one on a different graph

Tags: matlab

This was my attempt with 2 functions I'd like to plot side by side:

```
numgraphs = 2;
x = 1:5;
y1 = x.^2;
y2 = x.^3;

funcs = cell(y1, y2);

for i=1:numgraphs
    subplot(1,2,i);
    plot(x,funcs(i));
end
```

But I got this error:

```
Error using plot
Conversion to double from cell is not possible.
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

- Creation of the cell: you should use `funcs = {y1, y2};`, not `funcs = cell(y1, y2);`
- Plotting: you should use `plot(x,funcs{i});`, not `plot(x,funcs(i));`. The curly braces are used to access the *content* of the cell.

Answer (score 4):

Cell-indexing with `()` brackets returns a cell-array, not the function contained in this cell:

```
>> x = {1};
>> class(x(1))
ans =
cell

>> class(x{1})
ans =
double
```

You want `{}` indexing:

```
plot(x,funcs{i});
```

See 
http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html
for more info on that.